# Can I upload app with another minimum SDK support?

Tags: android, sdk

I have an app that runs on Android devices from Android 4.1 (API level 16). This is nice but almost all users (around 97%) run my app on Android 5.0 (API level 21)+ devices and there are almost no users with devices below Android 5.0.

Therefore, I would like to rebuild my app and make it available only for Android 5.0+ devices. However, I am not sure whether it would be accepted while uploading on Google Console.

Answer (score 1):

---

Why not? minSdkVersion is used to display your app on a particular device. If your minSdkVersion is 21. Your app will not be visible on the devices having Android version less than 21.

Comment: Yes, but Google Console says: Severe warnings
Check these severe warnings before starting the roll-out of this release. Addressing the warnings on this page will ensure that your existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app.

Comment: This says that your existing customer will not be able to get the upgrade to your latest app version if their devices hold the Android API version less than minSdkVersion.